# SQL SERVER 1 to many - groupby query

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 tables Categories & Subcategories

i need to create a query to display Category name and under each all subcategories (ID + Name)

Something like that:

```
Category1
Sub101
sub102
sub103

Category2
sub201
sub202

Category3
sub301
sub302
```

I know that I can count subcats for each cat, but i need to display their names as well.
I tried this query:

```
    select distinct CatID,  COUNT(SubcategoryID)
    from Subcategory
    group by CatId
```

another query :

```
    select distinct CatName, SubcategoryName , COUNT(SubcategoryName)
    from Categories, Subcategory
    group by CatName,SubcategoryName
```

I need to bind this later to a dropdownlist in asp.net

any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: can you post the query that you have *at least* tried?

Comment: you also need to post the db schema so we can write the queries properly for you!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
select distinct CatID, 0 as Header, CatName
from Categories
UNION
select distinct CatID, 1, SubcategoryName
from Subcategory
Order by CatId, Header, CatName
```

This uses the CatId to group all the categories and sub categories together. Then the 1\0 to ensure the Category sorts to the top and finally the CatName\SubcategoryName is sorted Alphabetically.

There may be a problem with selecting distinct from subcategories if they are reused, but we can cross that bridge if we come to it.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I had something similar.
the problem is Category name is always repeating. i want to display catName once and then all subs linked to that category

Comment: Can you confirm whether the Categories are repeating or the SubCategories ?

Comment: Slightly confused by what you are seeing. can you post an example ?

Comment: Slightly , I was confusing. I selected SubcatId instead of 0 as header and now it's clear :)
Thank you for your answer. it helped me a lot!

Comment: the pleasure is mine.

Answer (score 0):

Try using WHERE Exists clause, for example

```
SELECT
FROM 
WHERE EXISTS 
( SELECT            
         FROM 
         INNER JOIN       
         ON 
         WHERE "you can also use AND" )
GROUP BY
```

Hope this helps